# Gensim save_word2vec_format() vs. model.save()

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am using gensim version `0.12.4` and have trained two separate word embeddings using the same text and same parameters. After training I am calculating the Pearsons correlation between the word occurrence-frequency and vector-length.  One model I trained using `save_word2vec_format(fname, binary=True)` and then loaded using `load_word2vec_format` the other I trained using `model.save(fname)` and then loaded using `Word2Vec.load()`. I understand that the word2vec algorithm is non deterministic so the results will vary however the difference in the correlation between the two models is quite drastic. Which method should I be using in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this was intended as a comment. Don't know how to change it now, sorry

*correlation between the word occurrence-frequency and vector-length* I don't quite follow - aren't all your vectors the same length? Or are you not referring to the embedding vectors?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear - I am using the magnitude of the embedding vectors. I.e. ``numpy.linalg.norm(model[word])``